# Has the braiding pattern of circles with points infinitesimally close to the center been studied?

Tags: geometry, circles, knot-theory

Suppose I have $n$ circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at $(\epsilon^i_x,\epsilon^i_y)$ infinitesimally close to the center, with radii $r_i=1+\epsilon^i_r$ infinitesimally close to 1. In general this will produce a picture like this 
[image: Circles]

which has the following braiding pattern
[image: braiding pattern]

has the pattern been studied studied for arbitrary placement and number of circles?

Comment: What is the point of adding the word "infinitesimally" to your question?

Comment: I suppose I could just say close to the center. The point is that the braiding pattern is fixed in the limit of small distances from the center